# IntelliJ: Mapping ctrl-V to go into visual block mode for ideavim

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I've accidentally turned off ideavim's ctrl-V keybind to go into visual mode. How can I turn it back on again?

(I'm also using IntelliJ 13.1 for mac, so the path to change some settings may be different.)

Comment: I don't use ideavim, but all shortcuts can be changed at `IDE Settings` > `Keymap`. There is a filter to search for possible commands. For example, try `visual mode` etc.

Comment: Yup, that worked! Sort of. I think now I'm getting a bug where I could only select a max of one line above the cursor, but as many lines below... But thank you.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `IDE Settings` > `Keymap`, as mentioned by Darek Kay, you may also need to check the `IDE Settings` > `Vim Emulation` section, which lists conflicts between IDE key bindings and VIM bindings.  If you see `^V` listed there, you can select whether to handle that key with the IDE or with Vim.